# $\left(\int_{a}^{b}{fgh}\right)^4\le\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f^4}\right)\times \left(\int_{a}^{b}{g^2}\right)^2\times \left(\int_{a}^{b}{h^4}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $a$ and $b$ two real numbers such that $a<b$ and $f,g$ and $h$ three positives continuous functions over $[a,b]$. Show that: $$\left(\int_{a}^{b}{fgh}\right)^4\le\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f^4}\right)\times \left(\int_{a}^{b}{g^2}\right)^2\times \left(\int_{a}^{b}{h^4}\right)$$
I tried to use Cauchy Inequality three times but no issues. Any idea?

Comment: Use Hölder's inequality twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of using Cauchy is correct. One has
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f^4}\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}{h^4}\right) \ge \left(\int_{a}^{b}{f^2h^2}\right)^2$$
and
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b}{f^2h^2}\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}{g^2}\right) \ge \left(\int_{a}^{b}{fgh}\right)^2$$
from which the desired inequality easily follows.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(\int (fh)g\right)^4\le\left(\int f^2h^2\right)^2\left(\int g^2\right)^2\le\left(\int f^4\right)\left(\int h^4\right)\left(\int g^2\right)^2.
$$